# How to dynamically combine two arrays while making sure that they're evenly distributed?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

I'm trying to combine two arrays but have the second array evenly distributed in the first array. I'm open to not merging them if there's a nice loop solution to what I'm trying to solve where I just build a new array.

Array 1 looks like this:

```
    $array_1 = array(
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat')
    );
```

Array 2 looks like:

```
$array_2 = array(
    array('dog'),
    array('dog'),
    array('dog'),
    array('dog')
);
```

I want to merge these into one. The only kicker is I want to evenly space out the array 2 in array 1. To illustrate my question, this is what it roughly would like:

```
    $array_1 = array(
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),

        array('dog'),

        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),

        array('dog'),

        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),

        array('dog'),

        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),

        array('dog'),

        array('cat'),
        array('cat'),
        array('cat')
    );
```

This also needs to be dynamic since we don't know the size of array 1 or 2 (they will change in time). It needs to account for odd or even and be as perfectly distributed as possible. The only true constant is that array 2 will always be shorter than array 1.

The repeating arrays cat and dog are only for illustrative purposes. The actual values of these arrays can be anything so just assume that each is it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function. I assumed that the elements in both arrays may have different values and array keys may not be ordered.

```
function distribute($container, $distributed) {

    // reindex arrays
    $container = array_values($container);
    $distributed = array_values($distributed);

    $containerSize = count($container);
    $distributedSize = count($distributed);

    $partSize = floor($containerSize / $distributedSize);

    $newArray = array();

    $distributedKey = 0;
    $newArrayKey = 0;

    foreach ($container as $containerKey => $containerValue) {

        if (($containerKey >= $partSize) && (($containerKey % $partSize) == 0)) {

            $newArray[$newArrayKey] = $distributed[$distributedKey][0];
            $distributedKey++;
            $newArrayKey++;

        }

        $newArray[$newArrayKey] = $container[$containerKey][0];
        $newArrayKey++;

    }

return $newArray;

}
```

Comment: Didin't work as expected. Produced this: ["A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","A","A","A"].

Answer (score -1):

There can be many answers to this, but another way is to use `array_chunk`, to divide/distribute them accordingly, then push each content of the second array inside. Of course after chunking them, you'll need to flatten them out again.

```
$data = array_chunk($array_1, floor(count($array_1) / count($array_2)));
$result = array();
foreach($data as &$d) {
    if(!empty($array_2)) {
        $d[] = array_shift($array_2); // push inside the batch
    }
    $result = array_merge($result, $d); // flatten
}
```

[Sample Output](https://www.tehplayground.com/Wm7TSXwuvEq5kSPC)

Comment: Didn't work as expected.

Comment: yes it did based on OP's example https://www.tehplayground.com/Wm7TSXwuvEq5kSPC @digitalstraw

Answer (score -1):

I know it's dirty, but it works. So I'm open to contributions:

```
$catCount = count($array_1);
$dogCount = count($array_2);
$offset = $catCount / $dogCount;

for ($i = 0; $i < $dogCount; $i++) {
    array_splice($array_1, ($offset * ($i + 1)), 0, array($array_2[$i]));
}
```

Oddly, the second array needs to be wrapped in an array or it will not insert it as a nested array. Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: No, this didn't work well.